# Tensorflow saving and restoring a model in a compatible way (both eager and graph mode)

Tags: tensorflow

In graph mode, we use `tf.train.Saver`. In eager mode, we use `tf.contrib.eager.Checkpoint`.

However, it is not clear how to save on one and restore on another?

Answer (score 0):

I've just found that `tf.contrib.eager.Checkpoint` actually is designed to work with both eager mode and graph mode.

It can be used in the following way (let's say we have saved a checkpoint somewhere with eager mode, now we run in graph mode):

```
saver = tf.contrib.eager.Checkpoint(....) # same with both graph and eager mode
saver.restore(...).run_restore_ops() # run_restore_ops() is important in graph mode!
```

In short, I think it works if `.run_restore_ops()` is run.